# BeginPaint - заполняет структуру PAINTSTRUCT только из WM_PAINT

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так ?

Я создаю отдельный поток и создаю обычное WinApi-шное окно. И делая HWND окна глобальным.

В процедуре окна, когда оно вызывается с WM_PAINT, то после выполнения функции BeginPaint в структуре ps - заполнены размеры созданного окна:

```
HWND my_global_HWND;

static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND   hWnd, UINT   message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    if (message == WM_PAINT)
    {
        HDC my_hdc = BeginPaint(my_global_HWND, &ps);  
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
}
```

Но, когда я вызываю этот же BeginPaint из стороннего потока и не из процедуры окна, то BeginPaint так же выполняется, в my_hdc - заполнен значением, а не нулем.
Но структура ps - заполнена нулевыми размерами окна.

Не пойму почему так происходит.

Comment: BeginPaint/EndPaint только в процедуре окна при обработке WM_PAINT и должны работать. Если нужно контекст окна где-то в другом месте или при обработке других сообщений использовать, используйте вместо этого функции GetDC/ReleadeDC (соответственно)

Comment: Ну правда данные аналогичные paintstruct нужно будет как-то отдельно получать, навскидку не помню, надо гуглить. Для получения размеров окна - что-то типа GetWindowRect или GetClientRect (для получения размеров клиентской области).

Comment: Не трогайте окно из других потоков. Используйте PostMessage/SendMessage для связи с потоком окна. В WndProc обрабатывайте эти сообщения. Но и здесь не рисуйте окно напрямую. Делайте  Invalidate и рисуйте только из WM_PAINT.

Comment: @Alex F, WM_PAINT - вызывается только, когда окну требуется сделать перерисовку. А у меня само изображение может меняться между вызовами WM_PAINT, то есть мне все равно нужно вызвать функцию рисования между WM_PAINT`ами и это получается только из другого потока.

Comment: `WM_PAINT - вызывается только, когда окну требуется сделать перерисовку` Для этого вызывается функция InvalidateRect. Затем Windows асинхронно посылает WM_PAINT. То есть, когда надо перерисовать окно, вы меняете какие-то переменные (state machine) и вызываете InvalidateRect. В WM_PAINT рисуете окно в соответствии с текущим состоянием.

Comment: @Alex F, ооо, то что нужно. Спасибо!!